# Show correct answer in multiple choice app

Tags: android

Im doing a multiple choice apps with 4 choices. I've downloaded a code. But how to prompt the user of the correct answer if his answer is incorrect answer (at the same time).Here is a sample of the code. Correct answer is green. Wrong answer is red.

```
    optionOne.setOnClickListener(this);     //On First Option selection
    optionTwo.setOnClickListener(this);     //On Second Option selection
    optionThree.setOnClickListener(this);   //On Third Option selection
    optionFour.setOnClickListener(this);    //On Forth Option selection

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == optionOne.getId()){
        onOptionSelected(optionOne.getText().toString(), v);
        optionOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else if(v.getId() == optionTwo.getId()){
        onOptionSelected(optionTwo.getText().toString(), v);
        optionTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else if(v.getId() == optionThree.getId()){
        onOptionSelected(optionThree.getText().toString(), v);
        optionThree.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else if(v.getId() == optionFour.getId()){
        onOptionSelected(optionFour.getText().toString(), v);
        optionFour.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else if(v.getId() == pause.getId()){   //True when Game is Paused 

//When an option of a question is selected
private void onOptionSelected(String option, View v){
    if(!isGamePaused && !isGameEnded) { //true when game is being played
        ATriviaQuestion tTQuestion = myListOfTriviaQuestions.get(currentQuestionNumber);
        if(option.equals(tTQuestion.GetOptions().get(tTQuestion.GetAnswer() - 1))) {
            correct += 1;
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
        else{
            incorrect += 1;
            totalPoints -= pointsPerWrongAnswer;
        }
```

I need to insert a code on this portion to show the correct answer in green background if the user answer is incorrect but i don't know how.

```
else{
incorrect += 1;
totalPoints -= pointsPerWrongAnswer;
```

The database questions is in .plist

```
<question>
<key>Question</key>
<string>What is the ....</string>
<key>Options</key>
<array>
<string>option 1</string>
<string>option 2</string>
<string>option 3</string>
<string>option 4</string>
</array>
<key>Answer</key>
<integer>2</integer>
</question>
```

Here is my other code

```
public ATriviaQuestion(){
isThisQuestionAsked = false;
answer = -1;
answered = "";
}

public String GetQuestion()
{ return this.question; }

public void SetQuestion(String _question)
{ this.question=_question; }

public ArrayList<String> GetOptions()
{ return this.options; }

public void SetOptions(ArrayList<String> _options)
{ this.options = _options; }

public int GetAnswer()
{ return this.answer; }

public void SetAnswer(int _answer)
{ this.answer = _answer; }
```

Comment: You need to describe what you want a little better and exactly what is your question. "I need to insert something here..." does not tell us anything. How do you want to display the correct answer (`TextView`, `Toast`, `Alert`...)?

Comment: @codeMagic I want to get the position of the current correct answer and changed its background to green if the user answer is incorrect (show them both at the same time).  The code must be inserted in the else statement i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble following exactly what is what here but you can loop through your `options` until the text equals `tTQuestion.GetOptions().get(tTQuestion.GetAnswer() - 1)` (which appears to be how you are getting the correct answer) then set that `View`'s background color to green.

Comment: Thanks. The code is already working. Here is the current scenario. If I choose a wrong answer on my 1st, 2nd or 3rd try the background of all the incorrect answer will change to red  before I finally gets the correct answer. What i want to do is "if the user is incorrect on his 1ST TRY, the correct answer will also be showed in green at the same time". No more 2nd or 3rd try.